# Which anime episodes of bobobo-bo bo-bobo are based on which manga chapters?

Tags: bobobo-bo-bo-bobo

I like watching anime episodes based on which manga chapters I read. The wiki doesn't tell exactly which Bobobo-bo Bo-bobo episodes are based on which chapters?

Could someone tell me like they did with the Aria Manga?